# Two 'networks' via one PC

Tags: networking

Here is my situation:  I have a Windows 7 PC connected to my company domain/network via ethernet card. It uses a 10.200... ip, subnet 255.255.0.0.  We use this for internet/email/intranet, shared network folders, etc.

Now, I have a group of wifi temperature recording devices that need to connect to my PC which runs the temperature recorder software.  So I have a USB wifi-adapter connecting to a wifi router that has a 192.168... 255.255.255.0 configuration.

The wifi-router provides dhcp for the temp-recorders, and allows them to transmit to my pc.  There is no internet connection to the wifi-router.

So what happens when I have both enabled is that I can access the wifi-router in my browser, and the temp-recorders can download just fine.  But my internet doesn't work.

If I 'share' my ethernet internet connection I can then access the internet, but then cannot access the wifi-router, and the recorders disconnect.

Somehow I'd like to have both 'networks' accessible at the same time.

Comment: Is connecting the temp router to the normal internet an option

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not.  The temperature-router is free-floating without pc or internet connection, wifi-only.

When the wifi connection is active, my wired-ethernet internet doesn't work (but some networking does- email, shared folders).  Just nothing in a browser.  When wifi is disabled, I can access the internet again.

*** Just solved *** on the wifi adapter I set my IP manually with no default gateway.  Problem solved.  Both internet on wired-ethernet and control panel on wifi-router are accessible now, no problems.  I guess each adapter having it's own default gateway was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> The wifi-router provides dhcp for the temp-recorders, and allows them to transmit to my pc. There is no internet connection to the wifi-router.

As you have discovered, the default gateway from the wifi router causes an issue.  Default gateway means "IP address where I can get the Internet."

If your system has two it may use one default gateway as a backup, switch to the new one, or even try to load balance between them.

DHCP, in addition to assigning IP addresses, can also hand out other options such as DNS server and default gateway.  If devices behind the wifi router do not need Internet access, you ought to configure it's DHCP server to not hand out a default gateway.